# Display table with maximum height and a vertical scroll bar to width 100%

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with a lot of content, a maximum height, and a vertical scroll bar. There are several tables with different content, the lower example is a basic content. The table has a `table.vartable {display: block; width:fit-content}`:

[image: table 1]

Based on another content type, I need to change to `width:100%` but the `display: block` prevents the change from being successful:

[image: table 2]

Changing the display type either prevents the maximum height from showing the entire table or hides the scroll bar. I don't know what the solution is.

> **Important:** Each table can have from three to eight columns, but since the content of each cell is a word or number, they must always be visible, so a horizontal scroll is not a viable option.

```css
div {margin:0 auto; width:100%; text-align:center; padding:0;}

ul {list-style:none; margin:0 auto -0.25rem; text-indent:0;}

li {height:auto;  margin:0; text-indent:-2.5rem; display:none; }

table.vartable {border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
margin: 0rem auto;
max-height: 200px; 
overflow-y:auto; 
display:block;
border-top:2px solid #35D0CD;
border-bottom:2px solid #35D0CD;
}

table.vartable > thead > tr > th {
border-left: 2px solid #35D0CD;
border-right: 2px solid #35D0CD;
color: #35D0CD;
background-color: #1596A4;
text-align: center;
position: sticky;
top: 0;}
    
table.vartable td {
border: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #35D0CD;
padding:0 3rem;}

table.vartable tbody tr:hover {
  background: #98E7E6; cursor:pointer;}

table.vartable tbody tr:active {
  background: #1596A4;}

table.vartable tbody tr.highlighted td {
  background: #35D0CD; }




table.vartable::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 30px;
}

table.vartable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background: #35D0CD;
border: 3px solid #1596A4;
border-radius: 20px; height:120px!important;
display:block;
}
table.vartable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #1596A4;
    border-color:#0F7A86;
}
table.vartable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background: #0F7A86;
    border-color:#35D0CD;
}
table.vartable::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background: #ffffff;
border-right:2px solid #35D0CD;
border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>



<table id="tb_71591" class="table vartable is_sortable " data-random="71591" data-sort="yes" data-vartable_ajax="0" data-cartredirect="no" data-globalcart="1" data-preorder="" data-preorder_direction="">
    
<thead>
<tr>
  <th data-sort="float" class="vartable_sku"><span>Ref</span></th>
<th data-sort="float" class="vartable_variations pa-color">
  <span>
    Color
  </span>
</th>

<th data-sort="float" class="vartable_variations pa-forma">
  <span>
    Shape
  </span>
</th>
<th data-sort="float" class="vartable_price"><span>Price</span></th>
</tr>
    </thead>
  
    <tbody>
      
    
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10618</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="M1I" data-label="Forma">M1I</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10619</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="M2S" data-label="Forma">M2S</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10620</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="M2I" data-label="Forma">M2I</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10621</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="M3S" data-label="Forma">M3S</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10622</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="M3I" data-label="Forma">M3I</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10623</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="M4S" data-label="Forma">M4S</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10624</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="M4I" data-label="Forma">M4I</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10625</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="M5S" data-label="Forma">M5S</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10626</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="M5I" data-label="Forma">M5I</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10627</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="N1S" data-label="Forma">N1S</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10628</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="N1I" data-label="Forma">N1I</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10629</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="N2S" data-label="Forma">N2S</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10630</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="N2I" data-label="Forma">N2I</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10631</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="N3S" data-label="Forma">N3S</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="instock is_purchasable" data-price="7.70">
<td class="skucol">RTW10632</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_color" data-sort-value="3E" data-label="Color">3E</td>
<td class="optionscol attribute_pa_forma" data-sort-value="N3I" data-label="Forma">N3I</td>
<td class="pricecol">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>7,70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>
</td></tr>  
      
      </tbody>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the td has no width in addition to its padding value.
Just replace the class .vartable by this one:

```
table.vartable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0rem auto;
  max-height: 200px; 
  overflow-y: auto; 
  display: block;
  border-top: 2px solid #35D0CD;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #35D0CD;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.vartable > thead > tr > th {
  border-left: 2px solid #35D0CD;
  border-right: 2px solid #35D0CD;
  color: #35D0CD;
  background-color: #1596A4;
  text-align: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

table.vartable {
  width: 100% !important;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.vartable th,
table.vartable td {
  width: 1%; /* Adjust the width as needed */
  border: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #35D0CD;
  text-align: center;
}

table.vartable tbody tr:hover {
  background: #98E7E6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table.vartable tbody tr:active {
  background: #1596A4;
}

table.vartable tbody tr.highlighted td {
  background: #35D0CD;
}

table.vartable::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 30px;
}

table.vartable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #35D0CD;
  border: 3px solid #1596A4;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 120px!important;
  display: block;
}

table.vartable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #1596A4;
  border-color: #0F7A86;
}

table.vartable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background: #0F7A86;
  border-color: #35D0CD;
}

table.vartable::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-right: 2px solid #35D0CD;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: It works, but in tables with a larger number of columns (until 8), it activates the horizontal scroll, which is not an option in my case, the columns must always be visible

Comment: I update my code with all necessary classes for vartable class, so it works with more or less columns number

Answer (score 1):

@Danielillo

try adding this to your styles

```
table {
    width: 100% !important;
}

tr {
    width: 100% !important;
}

th {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50% !important;
    display: revert;
    min-width: 23vw;
    max-width: 24vw;
}

td {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50% !important;
    display: revert;
    min-width: 23vw;
    max-width: 24vw;
}
```

you can play around with the min and max widths of the td and th, its the cells themselves you need to increase the size of

Comment: It works, but in tables with a greater number of columns, it activates the horizontal scroll, which is not an option in my case, the columns must always be visible